# SQL Server UPDATE and set variables at the same time, operations order

Tags: sql-server

Why in this code @changed is correct, but @changed2 is incorrect? The purpose is to find out if the column value is changing in the update statement. I haven't found anything on this matter that can explain this to detail.

If I had to guess, SQL Server will FIRST set the variables using the current state of the row to be updated, when it's done with that it will actually update it. This is why @changed2 is 0, the column VALUE has not been updated when resolving the @changed2 variable so there we have to use the @newValue.

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#tmpTest') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #tmptest; 

CREATE TABLE #tmptest 
  ( 
     test_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
     value   VARCHAR(20) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO #tmptest 
            (value) 
VALUES     ('hello');
```

then run this code multiple times (you can run it several times, but don't execute the code above again!):

```
--then run this multiple times:
DECLARE @oldValue VARCHAR(20),
        @newValue VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT value
           FROM   #tmptest
           WHERE  test_id = 1),
        @changed  BIT,
        @changed2 BIT


--alternate values:
IF( @newValue = 'hello' )
  SET @newValue = 'goodbye'
ELSE
  SET @newValue = 'hello'

--see current data
SELECT *
FROM   #tmptest;

--update
UPDATE #tmptest
SET    value = @newValue,
       @oldValue = value,
       @changed = CASE
                    WHEN @oldValue != @newValue THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END,
       @changed2 = CASE
                     WHEN @oldValue != value THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                   END
WHERE  test_id = 1;

--see changed data:
SELECT *
FROM   #tmptest;

SELECT @oldValue oldValue,
       @newValue newValue,
       @changed  changed,
       @changed2 changed2
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The result of this code is actually undefined; mixing column assignments with variable assignments means all bets are off. Search for "quirky update" for more information (and also why people sometimes use this anyway).

Comment: this is incorrect, even Microsoft recommends it when simulating sequences for SQL 2008 R2 like set @NewSeqVal = CurrVal = CurrVal+Incr link here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number/

Comment: Well, I see they've even [updated the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms177523) to codify this form of the update. That same documentation also explains what you're seeing: "`SET @variable = column = expression` sets the variable to the same value as the column. This differs from `SET @variable = column, column = expression`, which sets the variable to the pre-update value of the column."

Comment: What the documentation fails to make clear, however, is that `SET @variable = column, column = expression` has the same semantics as `SET column = expression, @variable = column`. The assignment works the way it does not because of the way the expressions are ordered, but because all references to a column value refer to the pre-update value. (Conversely, the expression `@variable = column = expression` works in a unique way -- `column = @variable = expression` does not parse.)

Comment: And to come back to my earlier remark, which should be amended: it is documented *nowhere* (that I can find) that assignments to variables in `SET` will happen in any particular order, specifically, left to right. This is why something like `SET @oldValue = value, @changed = CASE [something based on @oldValue]` is slightly worrisome. (Having said that, it seems very likely that tons of code is implicitly relying on an evaluation order and Microsoft would be unlikely to actually break that.)

Comment: I agree, may I should create a bug or something on connect.microsoft.com just to let them know about this.

Comment: This type of thing has been encountered time and time again doing running totals. SQL Server MVP Jeff Moden has a spectacular article on the topic. There are a LOT of caveats about making this type of thing work correctly. It is undocumented behavior and borders on black magic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/ I can assure you that MS knows about this and it has been blogged about by a number of other MVPs over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing updates, SQL Server will read the original data before any updates are in place if it needs to know the value on the original record. Thus, in your example, the process would be something like this:

```
Read value as @OldValue
Compare @oldValue and value
    Set @changed
    Set @changed2
Update value from @newValue
```

This behavior is actually counted on in certain code involving reading, updating, and returning a pre-update value in one command, preventing other processes from retrieving the same value.